# Active phone call is terminated when received Voip Push Notification on iOS 13.1 beta

Tags: ios, call, voip

There are some issue on iOS 13.1 beta 3 with Voip Push  Notification. If device is in active phone call, this call is terminated by iOS when device receives the Voip Push Notification for our application.
Does anybody tried to send the Voip Push Notification during the phone call and what did happened?